Custom attribute modifying query string values before model binding in ASP.NET Core Web API
In an ASP.NET Core Web API, I have a controller where I bind the request model to query string parameters. Additionally, I've decorated the controller method with a custom attribute that modifies the query string before the binding occurs.
Problem: my request model isn't receiving the property value that is being set in the query string by a custom attribute. The custom attribute is supposed to modify the query string before model binding occurs, but the modified value does not seem to be picked up by the model when the controller action is invoked.
Question: how can I ensure the query string modification made by my custom attribute is picked up during model binding? Should I use a custom model binder instead, or is there a better approach?
Simplified code
[HttpGet("/api/mymethod")]
[SetupDefaultSorting]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyMethodResponse>> MyMethod([FromQuery] MyMethodRequest request)
{
    // request.Sort is not set to "myvalue"
}

public class MyMethodRequest
{
    public string Sort { get; set; }
}           
        
public class SetupDefaultSorting : ActionFilterAttribute
{       
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString());
        queryString["sort"] = "myvalue";
        context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?{queryString}");

        await next();
    }
}


In asp.net core,  model binding is executed before action filters, that's why you could change the value in httpContext but in your action method, you still get the unchanged queryString value.

I resolved the model binding issue by modifying the attribute implementation to adjust its position in the filter pipeline. Previously, it was implemented as an IAsyncActionFilter, which occurs after model binding. I changed it to an IAsyncResourceFilter, which executes earlier in the pipeline, before model binding.
public class SetupDefaultSorting : Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString());
        queryString["sort"] = "myvalue";
        context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?{queryString}");

        await next();
    }
}


Since we are using model binding attribute FromQuery now, we need to use custom model binding to change the query value. I just want to show why the filter doesn't work.
Acccording to this section, IActionFilter can help us change the arguments passed into an action, but since it run immediately before and after an action method is called, and both model binding and model validation occur before the execution of a controller action(we can see description here), so that we can see the httpContext request property is changed, but the FromQuery parameter value is still the same.

So that if we don't want to create a custom model binding type but just want to use a Filter, then we can modify the model too. Here's my code snippet. Just like what you can see, I have var model = context.ActionArguments["request"] as MyMethodRequest;, here the argument request is what I defined in the action method [FromQuery] MyMethodRequest request. I changed ActionArguments value to change the model binded value. It worked for me. But I still recommend using custom modelbinding, that looks better.
public class SetupDefaultSorting : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var queryString = request.QueryString;
        var queryCollection = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(queryString.ToString());

        if (queryCollection.ContainsKey("Sort"))
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.GetDisplayUrl());
            var query = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uriBuilder.Query);
            query["Sort"] = "myvalue";

            // Reconstruct the query string
            uriBuilder.Query = new QueryBuilder(query.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, v)))).ToQueryString().Value;
            context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        }

        var model = context.ActionArguments["request"] as MyMethodRequest;
        if (model != null)
        {
            // Modify the model as needed
            model.Sort = "New Value";
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
    }
}


The filter pipeline resource was helpful. I was seeking a solution that avoided the complexity of creating a custom binder or relying on a specific request model

Thank you for your update and sharing : )

For that you would need to take a look at how models are bound in ASP.NET.
There is good documentation on that: Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core
Here's sample implementation, that you need to further adjsut:
public class MyMethodRequestBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var sort = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("sort");
        // Apply some modifications.
        var newValue = sort.FirstValue + " desc";
        var newSort = new ValueProviderResult(new StringValues(newValue));
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue("sort", newSort);
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new MyMethodRequest { Sort = newValue });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

The usage:
[ModelBinder<MyMethodRequestBinder>]
public class MyMethodRequest
{
    public string Sort { get; set; }
}

